# calculating expectation of standard Brownian motion $W_t$

Tags: brownian-motion, expected-value, density-function

let $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion,

how can I calculate $E(W_t)$, I know the standard Brownian motion is symmetric, so this would be $0$ but how could I prove it via normal distribution?

and also $E(e^{t+W_t})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to note that the Brownian motion at time $t$ is distributed normally, with mean zero and variance (not standard deviation) $t$. To show that $\mathbb{E}[W_t] = 0$, you don't even need the fact about the variance. Just note that its mean is always zero.

To calculate $\mathbb{E}[W_t]$, note that you can first take $e^t$ out of the expectation (it is not a random variable). It remains to calculate $\mathbb{E}[e^{W_t}] = M(1)$, where $M$ is the moment generating function (MGF) of the random variable $W_t$. (You may recall that the definition of the MGF $M(\alpha)$ for a random variable $X$ is $\mathbb{E}[e^{\alpha X}]$.) We can again use the fact that $W_t$ is normally distributed. The MGF of a normal random variable is well-known:
$$M(\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)) = e^{\mu \alpha + \alpha^2 \sigma^2 / 2}$$
By taking $\mu = 0$, $\sigma^2 = t$, and $\alpha = 1$, we get that $M(W_t) = e^{t/2}$. Hence, $\mathbb{E}[e^{t + W_t}] = e^{3t / 2}$.